# Search on more than one index with different field

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have two indexes where two types of data are stored in OpenSearch.

1. Index: questions

   1. id
   2. questionText
   3. studentId
2. Index: bookmarks

   1. questionId
   2. studentId

I must now create a search query based on these two indexes. depending on the user ID, where I need to search the question. When I search, my search engine will return the answers to every question that the user has already asked and bookmarked.

Comment: you read this join field type [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html)?